# Interchange 2 variables in C++ with asm code

Tags: c++, assembly

I have a huge function that sorts a very large amount of `int` data. The code works fine except the fact that it's slower that it should be. My first step into solving this is to place some `asm` code inside `C++`. How can I interchange 2 variables using `asm`? I've tried this:

```
_asm{ push a[x]; push a[y]; pop a[x]; pop a[y];}
```

and this:

```
_asm(mov eax, a[x];mov ebx,a[y]; mov a[x],ebx; mov a[y],eax;}
```

but both  crash. How can I save some time on these interchanges ? I use VS_2010

Comment: How fast _should_ it be? What does the "slow" C++ code look like?

Comment: i interchange them using a secondary int like this: int c=a[x];a[x]=a[y]; a[y]=c

Comment: Have you looked at the code that your compiler generates? Do you think that your handed coded assembly code can be better?

Comment: You will not swap two integers faster than the compiler can.

Comment: Use `std::swap` instead of using temp `int` for exchange. I doubt it will be any better but it is more obvious what you are doing and less code.

Comment: when you say 'sort', do you mean you literally are just sorting? if so, maybe try to look for an optimized library. or does 'sorting' in this case mean something more?

Answer (score 4):

In general, it is very difficult to do better than your compiler with simple code like this.

A compiler, when faced with a swap operation on integers, will typically issue code like this:

```
mov eax, [x]
mov ebx, [y]
mov [x], ebx
mov [y], eax
```

Before you try to override, first check what the compiler is actually generating. If it's something like this, don't bother going any further; you won't be able to do better than this. Moreover, if you leave it to the compiler, it may, if these variables are used immediately thereafter, choose to reuse one of these registers to save on variable loads/stores as well. This is impossible with hand-coded assembly; the compiler must reload the variables after the black box that is hand-coded asm.

Note that the push/push/pop/pop sequence is likely to be much slower; not only does it add an additional four memory operations to the stack, it also introduces dependencies on the stack pointer, eliminating any possibility of pipelining. With the simple `mov` sequence, it is at least possible to run the pair of reads and pair of writes in parallel if they are on different memory banks, or one is in cache, etc. It also does not introduce stalls on the stack pointer in later code.

As such, you should not try to micro-optimize the cost of an interchange; instead, reduce the *number of interchanges* performed. There are many [sorting algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm) available, each with slightly different characteristics. You may find some are better (cause less swaps) on your dataset than others.

Answer (score 2):

What makes you think you can produce faster assembly than an optimizing compiler?
Even if you'll get it to work properly, all you're likely to achieve is to confuse the optimizer to produce even slower code.

Comment: i wrote 2 pieces of code in 1 program. The first piece interchanges 2 variables with an auxiliary one using c++ code and the second one interchanges them using asm code. I measured times for both and se second one is always faster. The problem is that when i try to implement this is my main program , it crashes. Can this happen because in my main code i use array and not simple variables ?

Comment: Perhaps the code is faster because it doesn't do the same thing (= is broken)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the variable names, function names and labels in assembly code as symbols. Note that things like `a[x]` is not such valid symbol.

Writing more efficient code takes skill and knowledge, using asm does not necessarily help you there.

You can compare assembly code that your compiler produces for both the function with inline assembler and without to see where you did break it.

Answer (score 1):

When you do in-line assembly, you can change things so that assumptions the compiler has made about register contents will no longer be true. Often times EAX is used to pass a parameter or return a value, so trashing EAX might not have much effect, but you clobbered EBX and didn't put it back, and that could cause problems. Try pushing EBX before you use it, then pop it when you are done.

Comment: but honestly, this kind of operation is old hat for optimizing compilers. before you go nuclear (i.e., asm), you should really consider the larger scale structure of your program.

Comment: @user775475 - you know though, the extra time for the EBX save will probably cost enough to make the C++ compiler's version faster, unless you factor it outside the loop.